# Passing Variables to Button Click Event

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I'm developing my near-zero c# programming via a very simple game in a windows form. On my latest form, I declare new variables with variables passed from other forms. However, I can't access variables from other methods.

```
public Form3(int str, int dex, int vit, int arc, int hp, int mp, int sp, string name, string charClass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int point = 0;
        int level = 1;
        int exp = 0;
        int hpPotions = 1;
        int gold = 20;
        int travelDistance = 1;
        nameBox.Text = name;
        maxhpBox.Text = hp.ToString();
        curhpBox.Text = hp.ToString();
        maxmpBox.Text = mp.ToString();
        curmpBox.Text = mp.ToString();
        maxspBox.Text = sp.ToString();
        curspBox.Text = sp.ToString();
        strBox.Text = str.ToString();
        dexBox.Text = dex.ToString();
        vitBox.Text = vit.ToString();
        arcBox.Text = arc.ToString();
        pointsBox.Text = point.ToString();
        levelBox.Text = level.ToString();
        expBox.Text = exp.ToString();
        classBox.Text = charClass;
    }

    public int TravelDecider()
    {
        Random travelInt = new Random();
        int travelValue = travelInt.Next(1, 10);
        return travelValue;
    }
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void rightBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int travelValue = TravelDecider();

        if (travelValue == 1)
        {
            locdescBox.Text = "During your travels, you encounter nothing of interest along the way. There is the occasional merchant or villager along the road, all seemingly bent on getting to their destination in good time.";
            travelDistance++;
        }
    }
```

The last bit of code with travelDistance++ is my issue as it doesn't exist in current context.

Some other solutions I found on other sites involved using get; set; (which I'm not at all familiar with) and other alternatives that were way beyond me.

Sorry after the fact as I'm sure this is a really beginner mistake, and I'm honestly not sure if Overflow welcomes people at this low of a level, so sorry if that's the case. If there's somewhere else I should be starting to develop a skill that ties into this, I'd welcome the advice. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `travelDistance` have a higher scope by declaring it outside the method. Thus making it accessible to all methods in that class.

```
private int travelDistance = 1;

public Form3(int str, int dex, int vit, int arc, int hp, int mp, int sp, string name, string charClass)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was a really simple solution. I appreciate the time you took to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now all your variables are declared within your constructor which makes them local variables, which basically means they are only accessible within the function they are declared.  (Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691170%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for more info)

Everything else you need to know is in Davids answer.

Comment: I'm reading through it all now. Thanks for the time you took posting the links. Sorry about that!